# RAD Studio XE7 Android Platform Missing

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

Yesterday I installed RAD Studio XE7 and when I started it for the first time I received Android package loading errors.  I have no Android platform.  When I look at the SDK Manager no Android as a possible add in the selection items which means I could not even add Android period.  The Android files are in their proper location.

I tried to repair the install and then modify the install.  No luck.

I am afraid I will have to uninstall RAD Studio and install it again, but with it taking almost 3 hours to install I am hoping to avoid this.

I also have XE5 and XE6 on my machine and they exhibited none of this bad behavior when they were installed.

Any suggestions short of a reinstall?

Comment: Yes. Contact [Embarcadero Technical Support](http://support.embarcadero.com). They offer free support for installation related issues.

Comment: And you bought the mobile add on right?

Comment: David, I am assuming you are talking about the Pro version what needs the mobile add.  We have the enterprise version.  Also, XE5 and XE6 are enterprise.

Comment: David, also iOS platform is loaded.

Comment: As Ken says, contact Embarcadero support at the link he provided.

Comment: Ken, I contacted support.  As I feared it looks a reinstall.  Thanks for pointing that out.  One thing that they said that I did not do is right-click admin privileges on the install.  Did not have to do that when installing XE5 or XE6.

Comment: The installer has the requiresElevation setting in the manifest. If that's the advice you have been given, then I doubt you've got through to anyone who really understands installers yet.

Comment: Reinstalled XE7.  Everything is fine.  Have no idea why this time it worked and not before.  Case closed.